# Simplest Bash code to find what files from a defined list don't exist in a directory?

Tags: bash

This is what I came up with. It works perfectly -- I'm just curious if there's a smaller/crunchier way to do it. (wondering if possible without a loop)

```
files='file1|file2|file3|file4|file5'
path='/my/path'

found=$(find "$path" -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex ".*\/($files)")

for file in $(echo "$files" | tr '|', ' ')
do
    if [[ ! "$found" =~ "$file" ]]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without invoking any external tools:

```
IFS="|"
for file in $files
do
    [ -f "$file" ] || printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will break if you have file names with whitespace. This is how I would do it, which is a bit more concise.

```
echo "$files" | tr '|' '\n' | while read file; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || echo "$file"
done
```

You can probably play around with `xargs` if you want to get rid of the loop all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ eval "ls $path/{${files//|/,}} 2>&1 1>/dev/null | awk '{print \$4}' | tr -d :"
```

Or use `awk`

```
$ echo -n $files | awk -v path=$path -v RS='|' '{printf("! [[ -e %s ]] && echo %s\n", path"/"$0, path"/"$0) | "bash"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

without whitespace in filenames:

```
files=(mbox todo watt zoff xorf)
for f in ${files[@]}; do test -f $f || echo $f ; done
```